# "Recently Visited Sites" Application in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Let me clear the air first: yes, this is classwork. No, I don't just want the answer. I am just really stuck and looking for some assistance.

I'll be as specific as I can. I think the best way I can do that is to post the prompt the book gives:

> Create a project named RecentlyVisitedSites that contains a Form with a list of three LinkLabels that link to any three Web sites you choose. When a user clicks a LinkLabel, link to that site. When a user's mouse hovers over a LinkLabel, display a brief message that explains the site's purpose. After a user clicks a link, move the most recently selected link to the top of the list, and move the other two links down, making sure to retain the correct explanation with each link.

My main problem with this is that I can't find a good way to make a "list" of the LinkLabels that both allows me to *use* LinkLabels in the first place *and* lets me rearrange items in a list-fashion. Here is my best go at it:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RecentlyVisitedSites
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        LinkLabel[] links = new LinkLabel[3];
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            /*LinkLabel[] links = new LinkLabel[3];
            links[0] = new LinkLabel();
            links[0].Text = "google.com";
            links[0].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 25);
            links[0].Links.Add(0, 0, "www.google.com");
            this.Controls.Add(links[0]);*/

            LinkLabel[] links = new LinkLabel[3];
            links[0] = googleLabel;
            links[1] = facebookLabel;
            linksPanel.Controls.Add(links[0]);
            linksPanel.Controls.Add(links[1]);
        }

        private void googleLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore", "http://www.google.com");
            links[0] = googleLabel;
            linksPanel.Controls.Remove(links[0]);
            linksPanel.Controls.Add(links[0]);
        }

        private void facebookLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore", "http://www.facebook.com");
            links[0] = facebookLabel;
            linksPanel.Controls.Remove(links[0]);
            linksPanel.Controls.Add(links[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

And I always get stuck either because the links won't show up, or I can't use them the way the prompt seems to want, or some other thing. The commented-out code is something else I tried using after asking my teacher, but I didn't get much out of our conversation and it didn't work either.

What should I be doing to get these links to display on page, in a list, where I can have them be clickable, open the stated web page in a browser, and be able to rearrange them the way the prompt asks?

Again, I'm not just asking to be given an answer, I have just hit a wall and I'm frustrated because I can't seem to find a decent explanation to help me understand what I actually need to be doing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't done Windows forms in a while, but I think you'll need a control like FlowLayoutPanel - that arranges its children automatically (if you set FlowDirection to TopDown, it will be vertical like you need). Then you can useFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex to rearrange items. Can you use WPF? This kind of thing would be really easy there.

Comment: @vesan Looks like that was the push I needed...thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Use this format for each `LinkLabel` on `Form1`:

```
LinkLabel.LinkVisited = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore, http://www.Facebook.com");
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this solution helps answer the question at all.